# Red5 crashes after couple seconds when using RTMPT

Tags: java, flash, streaming, red5

we've been having this problem for a long time and still cannot find out where is the problem. Our application uses RTMP for videostreaming and if the webclient cannot connect it skips to RTMPT (RTMP over HTTP). This causes the video to freeze after couple seconds of playback.

I have already found some forums where people seems to be havoing the same issue, but none of the proposed solutions worked. One suggestion was to turn of the video recording, but it didn't work. I have also read, that it seems to be a thread problem in the red5, but before hacking into the RED5 I would like to know, if maybe somebody has a patch or anything which repairs this.

One thing more, we've been testing this on Macs if that should count. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the very first thing you should look at is really the red5/error log.
Also Red5 occassionally produces output that might be *not* in the log but just to plain std.out
There is a red5-debug.sh or red5-highpref.sh that does output/log everything to a file called std.out.
You should use those logs to start your analysis. Eventually you will already see something into it. For example exception like:

- broken pipe
- connection closed due to too long xxx
- handshake error
- encoding issue in packet xyz
- unexpected connection closed
- call xyz cannot be handled
- too many connections
- heap space error
- too many open files

Some of them are operating system specific, like for example the number of open files. Some are not.

Also it is very important that you are using the latest revision of Red5 and not an old version. You did not tell us what version you are using.

However, just from symptoms like *video freezes* *occassional disconnects* or similar you won't be able to start a real analysis of the problem.

Sebastian

Comment: I have just found out, that the problem is with the Flash itself (https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-4797). If it skips to RTMPT it indefinitely enlarges the headers in the requests which at some point lead to proxy (or whatever) to refuse the requests. That is why we actually do not see anything in the red5 log, because there is no further communication. Now the question is, how to fix this, because doesn't seem to be doing something about that (why should they if it concerns Mac platform afterall :).

Comment: @Filip did you really monitor the raw packets with something like Wireshark and found this result? I am using RTMPT under OSX and never had this issue for years. Also the Jira issue you are refering to is resolved since 07/14/11 02:30 AM. I don't think that this the root of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Were you connected to the server when the video freezed? Or after that? I am not sure but I think connection closed which caused the stream to freeze.Just check in the access logs of Red5 if there are any logs for 'idle' packets(possibly after a 'send' packet(s) and more than one in number).

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could have a look at is your web server log files because RTMPT is over HTTP. I once had a problem with my anti DDOS program on the server. RTMPT will make many connections after each other and these TCP connections remain alive for about 4 minutes by default. You can easily get hundreds connections at the same time being seen as a DDOS-attack and as a result the IP-adres of the client will be banned.